# How to get the HTML text instead of the value from the dropdownlist using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'm trying to get the innerHTML/Text from the select options from a dropdownlist instead of the value.

`var Array = []; $('#select option').each(function(){Array.push(this.value)});`

The method above works, but it only stores the value attribute of the options.
For example, if my option were to be `<option value="John">Hello</option>`, It would store `John` instead of `Hello`. I want it to store whatever's in the innerHTML of the option. How do I go about doing this? `.innerHTML()` before the `.each()` doesn't work.

Comment: I would like to encourage you to change your variable name from `Array` to something else.  `Array` is the name of the javascript class for all primitive arrays(Ref. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).  I feel like naming your variable as such is a quick way to lead into unexpected errors.

Comment: Thank you for the information :), I just simplified the names to make it readable for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.innerHTML` **inside** the each

```
var Array = []; 
$('#select option').each(function(){
  Array.push(this.innerHTML);
});
```